# What is the term for pretextual basis?

Tags: legal-terms

Fred builds a unapproved structure which causes damage to an HOA.  He then persuades the board to build a structure to compensate / correct said damage under the guise of maintenance of said damage.

The guise of building the second structure as maintenance is pretextual. What is the legal term to capture the notion that the act building of building the compensating structure instead of removing the unapproved structure and correcting the damage is wrong?

Comment: This question was passed to English.SE and rejected because it is definitely a question regarding a term of art and better asked/answered on a specialist site.

Answer (score 1):

[Pretextual](https://thelawdictionary.org/pretext/):

> 1. The cover up of an actual fact with a weak or falsifying reason or motive. 2. The excuse to legalize an illegal activity